# How to Check inside JQuery which control has trigger it

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Lets say **TWO** `asp.net` controls trigger **SAME** `JQuery` function.
How can we check inside `JQuery` that which control has trigger it:

**asp.net**

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="R1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnClick="return Discount(this);"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="R2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnClick="return Discount(this);"/>
```

**JQuery**

```
function Discount(chk) {
  $(function () {
    if ( chk.id== $("#R1") )
      alert("Hi R1");

    if (chk.id == $('#R2')) 
      alert("Hi R2");
   });    
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of issues:

- `chk.id` will be a string but `$("#R1")` will be a jquery object - they will never be the same.
- `ID="R1" runat="server"` means the `id` will not be `R1` as asp.net "helpfully" tries to make the ID unique by adding the context.

so

- `$("#R1").length` will always ==0 because asp.net has broken your ID= for you (again "helpfully").

This is confirmed in OPs comment *it shows `"Hi contentBody_R1"`*

- `alert("Hi R1")` will *never* provide `"Hi contentBody_R1"` - so this is not the code that OP is running, likely they are running `alert("Hi " + chk.id)`

So you can't use `$("#R1")` unless you use the full id of `$("#contentBody_R1")` - which then assumes you're not going to move it into a different content to get a different `id`

The easiest option is to pass in the information you want on the call, eg:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="R1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnClick="return Discount(this, 15.0);"/>
<asp:CheckBox ID="R2" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnClick="return Discount(this, 17.5);"/>
```

```
function Discount(chk, discount) {
```

or store the information on the checkbox (may need some extra work if using server-side controls, but for an input it would be):

```
<input type="checkbox" id="r1" data-discount="15" onclick="return Discount(this);">
<input type="checkbox" id="r2" data-discount="17.5" onclick="return Discount(this);">
```

```
function Discount(chk) {
    var discount = $(chk).data("discount") * 1.0;
```

The other alternative, unless you *really* need autopostback on a checkbox (hint: you probably don't) is to use HTML rather than a server-side control, ie:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="r1" data-discount="15" onclick="return Discount(this);">
<input type="checkbox" id="r2" data-discount="17.5" onclick="return Discount(this);">
```

```
function Discount(chk) {
    if (chk.id == "r1")
```

in which case you *could* use `chk.id == $("#r1").attr("id")` but if you're finding by `id` then you already know the `id` so don't need to find.

Answer (score 0):

your tests are false, you have to write like this:

```
   function Discount(chk) {
      $(function () {
        if ( chk.id== "R1") 
          alert("Hi R1");
    
        if (chk.id == 'R2') 
          alert("Hi R2");
       });    
      }
```

you could simplify without if statement:

```
   function Discount(chk) {
      $(function () {
          alert("Hi " + chk.id);
       });    
      }
```

Comment: Nothing Happen. if i remove "if statemnet"  it shows "Hi contentBody_R1" and "Hi contentBody_R2"

Comment: its normal,  i dont understant, you want to remove if ? what do you want to do..its not clear

Comment: No. i dont want to remove if.. i just telling you what is printing

Comment: Use: `alert(chk.id)` (in the original code) - `chk.id != "R1"` (or "R2") because asp.net screws around with your IDs